# How to use google search by image in curl

Tags: javascript, shell, curl

I successfully do it with following:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="https://www.google.com/searchbyimage/upload" METHOD="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="encoded_image">
  <input type="Submit" name="sch" value="sch">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

when i select ~/Dropbox/img/green.jpg, and click "sch", it auto redirect to correct google result

[image]

but when i use following:

```
curl -i -F name=green.jpg -F filedata=@/home/roroco/Dropbox/img/green.jpg https://www.google.com/searchbyimage/upload
```

the google result show:

[image]

I hope search by image in curl how to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your form names don't match the values google image search is looking for. Your working test HTML file is submitting the file in `encoded_image` and is also providing `sch` from the input button, but you're submitting the file in `filedata` and a `name` in your curl command.

This is what worked for me locally:

curl -i -F sch=sch -F encoded_image=@path/to/my/imagefile.jpg  https://www.google.com/searchbyimage/upload

It also works without providing `sch` but I kept it to be consistent with your original form.

Answer (score 0):

@xorspark is right, I should use following code:

```
curl -i -F sch=sch -F encoded_image=@path/to/my/imagefile.jpg https://www.google.com/searchbyimage/upload
```

I wanna tell everybody how to find the name "encoded_image", in google image search page, when i click camera icon > upload an image, the form has name "encoded_image" like following:

[image]